# To find if a cell value is present in other column using excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

In excel, column A contains the list of words and column B contains its respective synonym. Sheet2 has a list of words in column A.

I want to see if the words present in column A of Sheet2 has any of the words present in column A or Column B of Sheet1. If yes, I would like to have the result in Sheet1 in front of corresponding word in column C

> ```
> Word          synonym
> abandonment   desertion
> abandonment   leaving behind
> abandonment   leaving
> abandonment   rejection
> abandonment   neglect
> abase         lower
> abase         demean
> abase         degrade
> abase         belittle
> ```

Final result required:

Loan mortgage mortgage   here morgage is returned from Sheet2.

Comment: Are those last lines supposed to be formatted in some kind of list? Please try to put some coding effort in it on your own. This site is meant to help answer questions on problems, not come up with complete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `find`-method to see if the word exists in sheet1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Have you ever written any VBA? I found OZGrid a good source to learn. Chapter 2 covers the find-method already: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson2.htm

Or can you be more specific about the problem you are facing?

Edit: don't have enough reputation to comment...

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using "vlookup" instead of macro? Below vlookup function will do the work I guess. In this function, excel is looking for the value in A1 cell within sheet2>A column and return a result if it can find it. If it can not find it, then it looks for the value in sheet1>B1. You can simply drag the formula.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE))
```